# iOS: Coredatabooks: Change UITableview

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data

I'm hobbying with the coredatabooks sample app--I'd like the UITableview to just be a list (that I can customize later). Right now it sorts by author.

1. What is the lingo I'm looking for?..different type of UITableViews?
2. How do I change this/customize TableViews?

Pretty simple and straightforward. I'm just a novice teaching myself for fun. (You're teaching me!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are just two types of UItableViews, plain or grouped.

You can do extra customization but I would first suggest you to read [this documentation on tableviews](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH1-SW1)